# Determine $\bigl\langle\bigcup_{\alpha} B_\alpha\bigr\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The statement is as follows:

let $ \{B_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in\mathbb{I}}$ be a family of subgroups. Determine:

$$ \langle \cup_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}\rangle $$

some idea? I know that in general family of subgroups is not a subgroup, and in the other hand $ \langle\cup_{\alpha}B_{\alpha}\rangle$ is the "smallest" subgroup that contains that family.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't more information in the context from which this was taken? As it is, you've basically said everything that can be said....

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each $B_\alpha$ is a subgroup of the same group, say $G$. Then by definition (as far as I know), letting $\Bbb S(G)$ indicate the set of subgroups of $G,$ $$\left\langle\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Bbb I}B_\alpha\right\rangle:=\bigcap\left\{S\in\Bbb S(G):\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Bbb I}B_\alpha\subseteq S\right\}.$$ This isn't very revealing in general, of course, but given some specific subgroups $B_\alpha$ and group $G,$ this can yield specifics.

Comment: yeah got this, and for example if $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B_1 = n\mathbb{Z}$ and $B_2 = m\mathbb{Z} $ what is the formula in this case?